# Redirecting incoming traffic from a referrer domain by country

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx

How can I redirect incoming traffic from a specific domain when user is from a specific country?

For example:

Mexican traffic coming from example.com to my site
AND
Chinese traffic coming from newexample.com to my site
AND
...

Thank You

[*****EDIT WITH MORE INFORMATION*****]

I'm looking for a code that redirects incoming traffic from the following example domains only if that traffic is also from the specified country in front of the domain in my list. please include my example domains and also the destination redirect url in the code you provide:

site1.com BRAZIL >> Redirect 
site2.com MEXICO >> Redirect 
site3.com CHILI >> Redirect 
site4.com ARGENTINA >> Redirect 
site5.com COLUMBIA >> Redirect 
site6.com INDIA >> Redirect 
site7.com INDIA >> Redirect

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $url = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=<API KEY>&ip=$ip&format=json";


        $ch = curl_init(); // start CURL
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // set your URL
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // get the response as a variable
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);      
        $response = curl_exec($ch); // connect and get your response 
        curl_close($ch);    
        $json_response = json_decode($response, true);

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($json_response);
        echo "</pre>";
?>
```

The above code will give you location of User based on his IP, now simply redirect user based on his location through some if else

Please note that you must sign up [here](http://ipinfo.info) to get api key in order to use this

Comment: Thank you, Where should I put the referrer domains and where should I put the destination url?

Comment: As I said, in json response you will get country name of visitor of website, for eg if it is $json_response = array("country" => "India"); then use if($json_response['country'] == 'India') header("location: index.php?country=india");

Comment: Thanks for your support but it seems like you didn't understand what code I want. this is not what I wanted. Please read my question again. I provided full information.